# Is it possible to manually input a command to Arena Chess GUI?

Tags: engines, arena

I want to manually input a single UCI command into my modded version of Stockfish to access my added functionality(a chat feature) and the incredibly useful `eval` command and then get the output. I'm using Arena Chess GUI, but I'm free for any other software recommendations.

I have seen some interesting stuff at Extras > Run Command line and Extras > Run Command but how am I supposed to use them? I don't even know what they do specifically, but seem something relevant.

Why am I not checking the documentation? Because there's none. I got Arena from http://www.playwitharena.de/ and there are only download links and there's also no documentation that came with my copy of Arena. And, third party docs are no way going to cover such technical stuff. I've tried, but found nothing.

And btw, this doesn't contain the `stockfish` tag because I'm using Stockfish but the question itself isn't engine specific. My version of Arena is 3.10beta for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. Open arena
2. Load engine
3. Press Engines->Log window
4. Press commands under Engine Debug window
5. In the dropdown textbox, input command like uci, etc. then press send button.
6. Also you can press help button to get help.
```